# this.state.someProp Does Not Exist on type ReadOnly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm not sure what type to specify for the component here for state to make TS happy.

For the line `!this.state.rendered` I get `this.state.rendered Does Not Exist on type ReadOnly`

```
    export default class TableOfContents extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {rendered: false};
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
            this.setState({rendered: true});
    
            setTimeout(() => {
                const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    
                if (el && document.getElementById('heading')) {
                    new Ink.UI.Sticky(el, {topElement: '#heading', bottomElement: '#footer'});
                }
            }, 200);
        }
    
        render() {
            if (!this.state.rendered) {
                return null;
            }
.. rest of the component
}
```

Comment: `Component` is generic - specify the shape of the state you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
export default class TableOfContents extends Component<MyProps, MyState> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { rendered: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ rendered: true });

    setTimeout(() => {
      const el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

      if (el && document.getElementById("heading")) {
        new Ink.UI.Sticky(el, {
          topElement: "#heading",
          bottomElement: "#footer",
        });
      }
    }, 200);
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.rendered) {
      return null;
    }
    // ... rest of the component
  }
}

type MyProps = {};
type MyState = {
  rendered: boolean
}
```